# How can a Docker container tell whether its memory was limited?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I'm using `cgget -n --values-only --variable memory.limit_in_bytes /` inside a Docker container to see how much memory it is allowed to use as per `docker run --memory=X`. However, I need to know whether the memory was limited at all, which isn't answered by the command above because it'd just give me a large number in that case (`9223372036854771712` in my tests).

So, is there any way to tell whether memory was limited at all? I'm looking for solutions that don't involve running `docker run` in a special way, like mounting files from the host (e.g., `/var/...`) or passing an environment variable.

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187085/check-mem-limit-within-a-docker-container/42188649#42188649

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could compare the total physical memory available to the number `cgget` gives you. If the number given by `cgget` is lower than the total physical memory, then you know for sure cgroups where used to limit the memory.

For instance if I run a container limiting the memory to 100M on my computer which has 2G of physical memory, `cgget` will report `104857600` while the `free` command reports `2098950144` bytes:

On the docker host :

```
# free -b
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    2098950144  585707520 1513242624     712704   60579840  367644672
-/+ buffers/cache:  157483008 1941467136
Swap:   3137335296          0 3137335296
```

Start a container limited to 100M

```
docker run --rm -it --memory=100M <any-image-with-cgget-available> bash -l
```

Now within that container:

```
# free -b
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    2098950144  585707520 1513242624     712704   60579840  367644672
-/+ buffers/cache:  157483008 1941467136
Swap:   3137335296          0 3137335296    

# cgget -n --values-only --variable memory.limit_in_bytes /
104857600
```

Note that the `free` command will report the same values on the docker host as from within the containers.

In the end, the following bash script defines a function `is_memory_limited` that can be used in a test to check if cgroup where used to limit the memory.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

function is_memory_limited {
    type free >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "The 'free' command is not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
    type cgget >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "The 'cgget' command is not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
    type awk >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "The 'awk' command is not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }

    local -ir PHYSICAL_MEM=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{print$2}')
    local -ir CGROUP_MEM=$(cgget -n --values-only --variable memory.limit_in_bytes / | awk '{printf "%d", $1/1024/1024 }')

    if (($CGROUP_MEM <= $PHYSICAL_MEM)); then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}


if is_memory_limited; then
    echo "memory is limited by cgroup"
else
    echo "memory is NOT limited by cgroup"
fi
```

Comment: Well on  my ubuntu 16, it read `cgget command not found` ; trying to install `apt-get install cgget` also failed. Please help!

Comment: Should anyone else search: they can be found in the `cgroup-bin` package

Comment: @johanvdw As of Ubunto 20 it's `cgroup-tools`.

Comment: When I run `cgget -n --values-only --variable memory.limit_in_bytes /` in my container (Ubuntu 20.04 running on macOS Docker Desktop 2.3.0.4 with `--memory=1536m`) I get `ULONG_MAX` (`9223372036854771712`).

Answer (score -1):

Just my 2 cents, rather than installing any third-party tools, you can simply check the limited memory using docker stats

```
docker container run --name mytestserver -m 200M -dt nginx
```

As in this case, I limited the amount of memory to 200M, now to verify it

```
docker stats <container id>

CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
3afb4a8cfeb7        mytestserver        0.00%               **1.387MiB / 200MiB**   0.69%               8.48MB / 24.8kB     39.2MB / 8.25MB     2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How can a Docker container tell whether its memory was limited?". The commands you're providing have to be used from the host machine.