# Check mem_limit within a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After some crashes with a docker container with a too low mem_limit, how can i check **in** a container the mem_limit of this container? I want to print an error message on startup and exit if the mem_limit is set to low.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked for me in the container, thanks for the ideas Sebastian

```
#!/bin/sh
function memory_limit
{
  awk -F: '/^[0-9]+:memory:/ {
    filepath="/sys/fs/cgroup/memory"$3"/memory.limit_in_bytes";
    getline line < filepath;
    print line
  }' /proc/self/cgroup
}

if [[ $(memory_limit) < 419430400 ]]; then
  echo "Memory limit was set too small. Minimum 400m."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I could see the memory limit in file `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`. What is "$3" in above answer?

Comment: this a little bit awk magic.    $3 is the third field separated by ':'   ..in plain shell it would be something like "cat /proc/self/cgroup|grep -E '^[0-9]+:memory:|cut -d: -f3  ....  same thing, but only  above in awk.  There are different memory limits in play if you are using docker, so /proce/self/group is the starting point to pick the right memory_limit

Answer (score 35):

The memory limit is enforced via cgroups. Therefore you need to use `cgget` to find out the memory limit of the given cgroup.

To test this you can run a container with a memory limit:

```
docker run --memory 512m --rm -it ubuntu bash
```

Run this within your container:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cgroup-bin
cgget -n --values-only --variable memory.limit_in_bytes /
# will report 536870912
```

Docker 1.13 mounts the container's cgroup to `/sys/fs/cgroup` (this could change in future versions). You can check the limit using:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

Comment: hmm, this seems not to work. it always gives me a huge value in the container  (9223372036854771712), which i guess is the total memory available in the system.   when i look outside at the "container stats" the 400m limit i have applied now, shows up though.  So still puzzled how to get the same value inside the container. This is centos container by the way running on docker 1.13 by the way.

Comment: @Mandragor You can also check in `/sys/fs/cgroup`. See my update. This also works in centos.

Comment: cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes returns 9223372036854771712.

Comment: found the value for my container. it is returned with cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/f7e5d4b494573004bc80ea0892459d4e19b0112ee64d0e1f9044579912a89f62/memory.limit_in_bytes.     How do I get the long container id, which is this increadible long string after ../memory/docker/...

Comment: try `cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "memory:/" | sed 's/\([0-9]\):memory:\/docker\///g'`

Answer (score 15):

On the host you can run `docker stats` to get a `top` like monitor of your running containers. The output looks like:

```
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
729e4e0db0a9        dev                 0.30%               2.876GiB / 3.855GiB   74.63%              25.3MB / 4.23MB     287kB / 16.4kB      77
```

This is how I discovered that `docker run --memory 4096m richardbronosky/node_build_box npm run install` was not getting 4G of memory because Docker was configured to limit to 2G of memory. (In the example above this has been corrected.) Without that insite I was totally lost as to why my process was ending with simply "`killed`".

Comment: this is the simplest way and reports the exact value put in `-m=value[m|g]`

Answer (score 7):

Previously the `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` worked for me, but in my ubuntu with kernel `5.8.0-53-generic` seems that the correct endpoint now is `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max` to recover the memory limit from inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check all values from the path defined in `/prof/self/cgroup` (example: `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1501.slice/session-99.scope`) up to `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` and look for the minimum. Here is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function memory_limit {
  [ -r /proc/self/cgroup ] || { echo >&2 "Cannot read /proc/self/cgroup" ; return 1; }
  path=$(grep -Poh "memory:\K.*" /proc/self/cgroup)
  [ -n "$path" ] || { echo >&2 "Cannot get memory constrains from /proc/self/cgroup" ; return 1; }
  full_path="/sys/fs/cgroup/memory${path}"
  cd "$full_path" || { echo >&2 "cd $full_path failed" ; return 1; }
  [ -r memory.limit_in_bytes ] || { echo >&2 "Cannot read 'memory.limit_in_bytes' at $(pwd)" ; return 1; }
  min=$(cat memory.limit_in_bytes)
  while [[ $(pwd) != /sys/fs/cgroup/memory ]]; do
    cd .. || { echo >&2 "cd .. failed in $(pwd)" ; return 1; }
    [ -r memory.limit_in_bytes ] || { echo >&2 "Cannot read 'memory.limit_in_bytes' at $(pwd)" ; return 1; }
    val=$(cat memory.limit_in_bytes)
    (( val < min )) && min=$val
  done
  echo "$min"
}
```

```bash
memory_limit
21474836480
```

In my situation, I have

```bash
cat /proc/self/cgroup
3:memory:/user.slice/user-1501.slice/session-99.scope
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1501.slice/session-99.scope/memory.limit_in_bytes
9223372036854771712
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1501.slice/memory.limit_in_bytes
21474836480 <= actual limit
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/memory.limit_in_bytes 
9223372036854771712
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes 
9223372036854771712
```

Thanks to Mandragor for the original idea.